# Remove characters (if found) in URL and then redirect jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, redirect

If an URL contains the word "hello", then remove "hello" from the URL and redirect. How is that possible? Example:

http://hello.google.com/

On page load, I want to check if "hello" is found, and then do a:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (url.match(/hello/)) {
    window.location.href = url.replace(/hello/, 'www');
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need for jquery here:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(location.href.indexOf('hello') > -1){
        location.href = location.href.replace(/hello/,'www');
    }
};
```